# how to synchronize user-added dictionary entries between apps and devices?

Tags: sync, dictionary

Is there an easy solution or app for synchronizing entries manually added by the users into the spelling dictionaries of e.g. office apps, web browsers, email client and so on between those apps and maybe even over several devices?

I only found the following useful but less helpful resources so far:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=409969
- https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/137568/feature-writer-sync-your-dictionaries/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's possible, but it will depend on how the dictionary is stored, whether it is encrypted, whether it can be copied/pasted, and a host of other factors. Please focus your question on a specific app in order that we can work to find you the answer for that.

Comment: Sorry, we generally don't do software recommendations here. You might want to try asking over on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, you'll have better luck.